# Form Based Authentication problem?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, security

i have 2 pages : Login.aspx and Satis.aspx. i redirected from Login.aspx to Satis.aspx if authentication is correct . if i signout from satis i redirected to Login.aspx. But if i write satis.aspx' url on web scanner i entered satis.aspx. But i am not sign in Satis.aspx. i should't enter Satis.aspx directly.

my web config:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" path="/"  protection="All">
                <credentials>
                    <user name="a" password="a"></user>
                </credentials>
            </forms>
        </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>


    </system.web>
    <location path="~/ContentPages/Satis/Satis.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

**Login.aspx.cs:**

```
   protected void lnkSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if(FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(UserEmail.Value,UserPass.Value))
            {
                  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage
                   (UserEmail.Value, PersistForms.Checked);
            }

             else
                Msg.Text = "Invalid Credentials: Please try again";

        }
```

**Satis.aspx**

```
 protected void LogoutSystem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            Response.Redirect("~/Login/Login.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: please rephrase your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use "deny users="?"" instead of "allow users="*"" in your web.config file

[*] means all users even those who did not pass authentication

[?] means only users who passed authentication

Comment: if you can not write these   <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

for Login.aspx. i writed it for Satis.aspx

Comment: Not sure that i got your question. If you don't want to put that changes in the config file, you may use "if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) Response.Redirect("Login.aspx"); in your Satis.aspx page